# How to use callback function in C++ library files?

Tags: c++, callback, function-pointers, libraries

I am working on a developing a library. I want to use a callback function in the library to register events which will be called from the Lua environment. My library has all lower layer functions (in files -reg_callback.cpp & reg_callback.h). All higher layer functions will be in Lua environment (Lua-script).

http://opensourceforu.com/2012/02/function-pointers-and-callbacks-in-c-an-odyssey/

With reference to this link, under A simple callback function; my main() is in Lua script and I have a Lua wrapper in the library. My code looks like this.

```
enter code here typedef void(*callback)(char*); <br/> bool register_callback(callback ptr_reg_callback); <br/>// reg_callback.cpp bool <br/>register_callback(callback ptr_reg_callback)<br/> {
          <br/>  (*ptr_reg_callback)();
          <br/>  return true;<br/>} <br/>// Lua_wrapper_for_callback.cpp <br/> reg_callback obj; <br/>int luaWrapper_register_callback (lua_State *L) <br/>{ <br/>if (obj. register_callback())                                          //Not sure what argument to pass here
```

{
     
                           lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
          
                      lua_pushnumber(L, 0);
               
 }
                
 return 1;
} 
//Lua-script 
obj = require("library")
local functionTest(f_cMessage)
print("\nTesting........Test function", f_cMessage);
end 
local register = obj.register_callback (Test()); 
print("\nPrinting: ", register)

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Your sample program does not give right picture of what you want. What do you mean by overloaded? Do you want to use Function Objects? If you are using plain func pointers then, at any time you can assign function pointer with different functions from wherever you want.

Comment: Let me re pharse the whole question.

Answer (score -3):

An example from 'Wireshark' (packet-gsm_a_rp.c).

```
guint16 (*rp_elem_fcn[])(tvbuff_t *tvb, proto_tree *tree, packet_info *pinfo, guint32 offset, guint len, gchar *add_string, int string_len) = {
/* Short Message Service Information Elements [5] 8.2 */
de_rp_message_ref, /* RP-Message Reference */
de_rp_orig_addr,   /* RP-Originator Address */
de_rp_dest_addr,   /* RP-Destination Address */
de_rp_user_data,   /* RP-User Data */
de_rp_cause,       /* RP-Cause */
NULL,   /* NONE */
};
static guint16 de_rp_message_ref(tvbuff_t *tvb, proto_tree *tree, packet_info *pinfo _U_, guint32 offset, guint len _U_, gchar *add_string _U_, int string_len _U_)
{
 guint32    curr_offset;

curr_offset = offset;

proto_tree_add_item(tree, hf_gsm_a_rp_rp_message_reference, tvb, curr_offset, 1, ENC_BIG_ENDIAN);

curr_offset++;

/* no length check possible */

return(curr_offset - offset);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.